# How can i specify the format for xticks/xlabel on a plot

Tags: plot, matplotlib, label

when setting up a plot for matplotlib, i run into very large numbers.

in one plot, these get converted into the scientific format, which i like, 
in another one they don't get converted. How can i specify this behaviour?

example where it works as i like it:
[image]

example where it does not work as i want it:
[image]

i am using matplotlib version 0.99.1.1.

Comment: i understand users sticking to stable version, but your matplotlib is way outdated !

Comment: its part of the ubuntu lts ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [plt.ticklabel_format](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format) :

For example:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='x',scilimits=(0,0))
```